# ckeditor in drupal : not showing in edit page

Tags: drupal, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor in drupal

its setup ok and showing in pages and story very well, but it is not showing in edit pages

I am using Visibility Setting

```
Include

node/add/*
*.edit-body
```

node/add/* for the pages and story - **showing properly**

*.edit-body for edit page - **not showing**

I also try

```
*.*
node/*/edit
```

even tried hard-coded

```
page@node/3/edit.edit-body
node/3/edit.edit-body
```

Page ID is

```
CKEditor: the ID for excluding or including this element is page@node/3/edit.edit-body.
```

Can Any body tell me where I am wrong

**Amit Battan**

Comment: hey drupal guys is any solution for this problem...
I tried a lot of combination of page id....

is there some other mistake...
I am new in drupal .. please guide me...

Answer (score 1):

I has the similar issue with my CKeditor

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26644/ckeditor-not-displaying-text-on-edit-node-option/26751

It worked when i updated the Ckeditor module.